# Understanding React hook useEffect & best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a personal greeting component that is setup like:

```js
const PersonalGreeting = (): ReactElement => {
  const [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState(null)
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date())
    }, 1000)

    setTimeOfDay(getTimeOfDay(date))

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [date])

  return (
    <>
    Good {timeOfDay}, Name
    </>
  )
}
```

When I `console.log` outside of the `useEffect` function, it seems to run twice. Inside the `useEffect` function it runs once, I was wondering if I was setting this up incorrectly or if there was a better way of doing this.

Helper function -

```js
const getTimeOfDay = (date: Date): string => {
  let timeOfDay = ''
  const hour = date.getHours()
  const minute = date.getMinutes()
  const isOClock = minute === 0

  if ((hour >= 4 && hour < 12) || (hour === 12 && isOClock)) {
    timeOfDay = 'Morning'
  }

  if ((hour >= 12 && !isOClock && hour < 17) || (hour === 17 && isOClock)) {
    timeOfDay = 'Afternoon'
  }

  if ((hour >= 17 && !isOClock) || hour < 4) {
    timeOfDay = 'Evening'
  }

  return timeOfDay
}
```

Comment: Log twice *outside* effect, as in the body of the functional component, usually means you are rendering your app into a `StrictMode` react component that renders your component twice to detect unintentional side-effects. Also, the interval callback updates the `date` state which triggers the effect callback again which tears down the previous interval and creates a new one, this is all likely completely unnecessary. I'm not sure what your goal is here though to make a good suggestion.

Comment: isn't it also because useEffect runs AFTER the first render? so logging in the fn body it logs once, executes the useEffect, which triggers a rerender, and logs twice. inside useEffect it logs only the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned best practice so I'll just cover what occurs to me. There's actually a lot of cool things at play here.

As others have mentioned `useEffect` runs *after* every render, including the first. It's effectively both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Render is running twice because the `useEffect` is changing react state after the first render.

- First Render -> Sets up effect
- Effect triggers immediately afterwards -> changes `timeOfDay`
- React runs render again to deal with the new state of `timeOfDay`

The simplest fix would be to set the first `timeOfDay` as a default during the first render. This way it won't have to change during the effect.

```js
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
  const [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState(getTimeOfDay(date))
```

Then move the code to set `timeOfDay` inside the interval with `setDate`.

You can actually do better, though, because just by putting the time of day in react state you're breaking the minimal essential state principle, which is fairly important in declarative programming. (note: I just made up that term. I don't think there's a good term for it yet.) What I mean by this is that `timeOfDay` is *entirely* derived from `date`, which is already in react state, so there is no reason (besides performance issues) to have both held in react state. Anytime this happens you should consider eliminating the redundant state. In this case this would involve deleting the `timeOfDay` state and just writing

```
    <>
    Good {getTimeOfDay(date)}, Name
    </>
```

As far as I can tell, the *only* reason to ever hold onto `timeOfDay` as state is if your `getTimeOfDay` were expensive and if rendering happened more often than once a second, but even in that case you would just want to use reacts memoization. That would look like

```
const timeOfDay = useMemo(() => getTimeOfDay(date), [date]);
```

Looks similar, right? It's basically the same, but it only runs during the render, and therefore can't cause the double render issue you're having. Specifically, `useMemo` will run `getTimeOfDay` during the first render, but then will only rerun `getTimeOfDay` on any subsequent render if `[date]` has changed; otherwise it will return the previous `timeOfDay` that was used.

One last thing worth mentioning. You pass `[date]` into your `useEffect`, but this is actually wrong. It will work, but it's not the intended use case. That array is used to tell react what state the effect function is **reading from** to cause its side-effects, but you're not *reading* from date, so you don't need to rerun the effect when `date` changes. What you really want is to pass in `[]`—no state. That way react knows that you side-effect doesn't depend on anything, and should only run once during the first render. Right now your use of an interval rather than a timeout is kind-of pointless, as react is canceling and reestablishing the interval on every render.

With all the changes I've described so far your component would look like.

```
const PersonalGreeting = (): ReactElement => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date())
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    `Good ${getTimeOfDay(date)}, Name`
  )
}
```

I also switched to string templating, which I think is nicer, but that's more of an opinion.

Comment: So I don't see `useMemo()` being used here, would you recommend using this still?

Comment: Not for this one. At the moment the component is only rendering when `date` changes, so `getTimeOfDay` has to be recomputed every time anyways. `useMemo` wouldn't actually cut out any computation. `useMemo` would be helpful if you had some other piece of unrelated state, such that `PersonalGreeting` had *some* reason to render without `date` having changed.

Comment: That is what I thought! Thanks

Comment: I figured out a way to use `useMemo()` see below and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Final version:

```
const PersonalGreeting = (): ReactElement => {
  const [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState(getTimeOfDay(new Date()))

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeOfDay(getTimeOfDay(new Date()))
    }, 60000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <PersonalGreetingContainer>
        <PersonalGreetingHeading weight="light">
          Good {timeOfDay},{' '}
          {givenName}
        </PersonalGreetingHeading>
      </PersonalGreetingContainer>
    )
  }, [givenName, timeOfDay])
}
```